# Graphing unique count of node in Graphite metric over time

Tags: metrics, graphite, statsd

Given StatsD/Graphite data points that look like this

```
stats.counters.post.topic_1.user_1.count
stats.counters.post.topic_1.user_2.count
stats.counters.post.topic_2.user_3.count
stats.counters.post.topic_2.user_4.count
```

I'm trying to chart 3 different things

- Number of posts
- Number of topics
- Number of users posting

So far I've got number of posts with

```
alias(summarize(sumSeries(stats.counters.post.*.*.count),"1hour"),"Total Posts")
```

For topics and users, I'm a little stuck.

I can get a series/line per topic with this:

```
aliasByNode(summarize(groupByNode(stats.counters.post.*.*.count, 3, "sumSeries"), "1hour"), 0)
```

But, this gives the number of posts per topic, not the number of topics.

How would I get the number of topics over time? From that, I'm sure I can apply the same for users.

Answer (score 4):

You can `offset` and `scale` a `SumSeries` which will give you your change over time rather than a flat line. Something like:

```
alias(
  sumSeries(
    offset(
      scale(stats.counters.post.*.user_2.count, 0), 1)
    ), 'Total Number of Topics')
```

More on this at [Counting the Number of Metrics Reported](http://obfuscurity.com/2013/05/Graphite-Tip-Counting-Number-of-Metrics-Reported)

Comment: In my case this is somehow showing fractional values though, like 17.3 users... am I missing something here? The count over time should always be integers

Answer (score 2):

Use the [countSeries(*seriesList)](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.countSeries) Graphite function.

Number of unique topics:

```
countSeries(stats.counters.post.*.user_2.count)
```

Number of unique users posting:

```
countSeries(stats.counters.post.topic_2.*.count)
```

Comment: I did find that and it seemed promising. But, it doesn't track change of the number over time, just shows the last count as a horizontal line.

Comment: Yes for me the countSeries's result didn't change if I changed the time interval. Can I use some other function instead of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue with `countSeries`. I wanted something across time. For me the solution was:

```
sum(isNonNull(groupByNodes(stats.counters.post.*.*.count, "sum", -3)))
```